# How was the onset of the Cambrian period dated?

Tags: earth-history, fossils, stratigraphy, dating

What dating method was used to determine the beginning of the Cambrian, and what was its margin of error? Was only one fossil dated, or were a number of similar fossils used?

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I already knew the dating was radiometric.

Comment: @MichaelWalsby other people don't know that until you say so. Can you add some more detail to your question? I think I can see what you are asking. While radiometric dating can generate the age of a given object, to determine the beginning or end of a period in geological history requires much more than that.

Comment: @uhoh i removed my comment,i still think the question needs some work.

Answer (score 4):

Fossils are only in very rare cases dated directly, because they do not contain sufficient radioactive isotopes for dating.
Most geological periods are first and foremost defined by biostratigraphy- fossil assemblages, typically. 
The Cambrian period starts with the Fortunian stage - this stage is defined by the appearance of a certain trace fossil in Fortuna peninsula, eastern Canada, but is correlable with similar formations world wide. The whole discussion on how this stage is defined is available [here](https://stratigraphy.org/gssps/fortunian).
As outlined in this paper, in addition to fossils, the Fortunian stage hosts various volcanic rocks which contain zircons, which can be dated by U-Pb. The age of the actual boundary is then interpolated from these data.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give some complementary informations from the other answer: the base of the Fortunian is indeed defined in eastern Canada on the basis of a **trace** fossil (which obviously cannot be itself dated since it is just an imprint), *Trichophycus pedum*. This trace fossil however being spread worldwide help correlating various sections throughout the world. One of such section is the  Birba-5 well in Oman where the radiometric age was actually measured (at least the one currently considered as the proper age of the base of the Cambrian): volcanic ash bed BB5 could be dated using $\ce{^{206}Pb/^{238}U}$ radiometric dating at 541 +/- 0.63Ma, based on the analysis of 8 different zircon grains.

It also corresponds to a negative carbon isotope excursion.

See the Cambrian chapter and the Appendix 2 on radiometric ages in [Gradstein et al. 2012](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780444594259/the-geologic-time-scale). Or [Bowring et al. 2007](http://nora.nerc.ac.uk/id/eprint/3262/1/Bowring_et_al_AJS_2007.pdf) for the original data.

Comment: Note that the margin of error given here is the one from Gradstein et al. 2012 where they recalculated it apparently (though given i am not a specialist I don't think i can explain correctly that computation).